# How to ask for NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription manually?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

In IOS there is a permission `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription`
and I would like to ask for it when my app is started for the first time.
So I want just to check if it is permitted and ask for it.
What I can do to force this permission check?

Answer (score 2):

You can request with `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(_:)` and check status with `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus`

See: [Apple docummentation for requestAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly discourage you from asking this when your app is started for the first time. It is much better to wait until the app needs to use that functionality when you have an opportunity to explain to your users why the app is asking for that permission.

Your app can only ever ask for this permission once, and without the proper context of why it is asking, users are much more inclined to decline the permission. You will get a much higher percentage of users granting permission if they better understand the benefit they will receive by granting it.

Comment: I know that but I have such a requirement. I just don't know how to force it.

Comment: Bummer. Well, maybe someone with a a better client can benefit from this answer. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is if the user denies. In this case, you as a developer, have to detect the user's current choice and notify him what to do. So how to detect the status of `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription `?